# sqlite in-memory database persisting between executions

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, in-memory-database

In the code below, I was expecting the in-memory database to be deleted when the connection closes as described at https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    var connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory");
    var statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab (name);");
    statement.execute("INSERT INTO tab (name) VALUES ('foo');");
    var result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from tab;");
    while (result.next()) {
        System.out.println(result.getString("name"));
    }
    connection.close();
}
```

In fact what I see is that each time I run this code there is an extra row in the table implying that the database is persisting between calls. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was a simple error. The connection string should have been:

```
var connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

The missing final `:` meant that it was interpreting it as as a database called "memory".